# Allow colon (:) in URL for ASP.NET Core in IIS/Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis, asp.net-core

I've got an ASP.NET Core app that I'm deploying to Azure that takes in a string in the URL that contains colon (a time stamp).

For example: `http://localhost:5000/Servers/208.100.45.135/28000/2017-03-15T07:03:43+00:00`, or `http://localhost:5000/Servers/208.100.45.135/28000/2017-03-15T07%3a03%3a43%2B00%3a00` URL-encoded.

This works perfectly fine when running locally using Kestrel (`dotnet run`), but after deploying to Azure I receive this error: `The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`

A quick search reveals that it's due to invalid characters being used in the URL, namely the colon. The traditional fix is to add this section to `web.config`:

```
 <system.web>
     <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" />
 </system.web>
```

However, after adding this to my web.config on Azure, I observe no change. I imagine this is due to differences in ASP.NET Core's hosting model.

Here is my current `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters=""/>
        <pages validateRequest="false" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Server.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And the relevant controller header...

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{serverIpAddress}/{serverPort}/{approxMatchStartTimeStr}")]
public IActionResult GetMatchEvents(string serverIpAddress, string serverPort, DateTimeOffset approxMatchStartTimeStr)
{
    ...
}
```

How can I get IIS/Azure to allow the colon character in URLs?

Comment: That's a colon, not a comma, and it's technically invalid in the path portion of a URL per RFC 3986. They should be URL-encoded (`%3A`), which should stop that warning from appearing, and they should be automatically decoded when you read in the query string parameters in your application.

Comment: D'oh, total brainfart on 'comma' vs 'colon'. Unfortunately, trying a URL that has URL encoded colon characters results in the same error. Tested with `/Servers/208.100.45.135/28000/2017-03-15T07%3a03%3a43%2B00%3a00`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue you're running into isn't related to the colon (:) in the path, it's really the [plus (+) that IIS doesn't like](https://blogs.iis.net/thomad/iis7-rejecting-urls-containing). It doesn't matter if the plus is encoded as "+" or "%2B". You have two options:

1. Move the plus/DateTimeOffset from the path to the query string where IIS doesn't mind it.
2. Configure the IIS request filtering module to "allowDoubleEscaping".

Example web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
        </security>
        <handlers>
            <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Server.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The system.web section of your current web.config isn't relevant to ASP.NET Core.

Comment: "The system.web section of your current web.config isn't relevant to ASP.NET Core.", thanks, but what would it be?

Comment: @Arendax It depends on what you're trying to configure. In this case it was system.webServer>security>requestFiltering. For other config, I recommend asking a new SO question.