# Asp.Net MVC Core enabling double escape

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on a asp.net mvc core application and trying to allow double escaping.

My Edit url has a phone number as hyperlink (Ex: +123). I know how to do with a normal asp.net mvc application. I used to change web.config file as

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true"/>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

But I am right now on Asp.Net MVC Core application with out a web.config. How and where can I manage this?

Comment: This looks very, very similar, can you try this and update the question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42846612/495455

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ASP.NET Core application [could be hosted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosting?tabs=aspnetcore2x) on variety of web servers (IIS, Kestrel, Nginx, Apache, ...). All these web servers know nothing about [request filtering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/) (and particularly enabling of double escape) which is a native IIS feature. It's a hosting concern and ASP.NET Core application should not deal with it directly. If URL like `http://youserver.com/Home/Phone/+12345` will reach ASP.NET Core pipeline, plus sign will not be treated in any special way and will get to string model as `+` character.

When you host your application on IIS, web.config is still in use, so you could configure `<requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true"/>` as for usual ASP.NET application. Again, you should not be afraid that you do something in non ASP.NET Core way. You configure a hosting concern; it's not the field of ASP.NET Core.

If you want to host application in another Web server, you should check how it handle special characters. I know that Kestrel will just pass such URLs as is, so you don't need to take any specific actions if hosted on Kestrel.

Comment: @Kurkula, I have revised my answer in part of non-IIS hosting. I have overcomplicated it at first. After considering it a bit, I realized that no custom middleware is actually required.

Comment: To allowDoubleEscaping during development with IIS Express here's what I did: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56463044/381082

Answer (score 5):

You should use the [web.config transformations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/transform-webconfig?view=aspnetcore-3.1) - or you'll wipe it out next time you deploy and your customer will come back and say 'hey it broke again!'

Create a `web.Release.config` file (you don't need a `web.config` file in your actual project) with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <location>
    <system.webServer>

      <security xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
        <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
      </security>

    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

When you publish a release build this will get added - as well as all of the aspNetCore handlers. Very important to include the part `InsertIfMissing` or it will be ignored.

You DON'T need a third party package such as [this](https://github.com/nil4/dotnet-transform-xdt#-use-with-msbuildcsproj-tooling). 7