# allowDoubleEscaping on .net core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, appsettings, asp.net-core-identity

I am using asp.net identity and GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync gives me a token for email confirmation. I cannot use this code in confirmation url, because it gets an error :

> The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that contains a double escape sequence.

The solution for that issue was to allowDoubleEscaping in web.config, but how can I do it in appsettings.json? I should write this code somehow in appsettings, or in Startup.cs:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true"/>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49664759/asp-net-mvc-core-enabling-double-escape ?

Comment: I am running into this issue as well. How frustrating it is for MS to have a function for creating confirmation tokens that contains this type of error.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

It's still an IIS setting if you're running in IIS.

Create a `web.Release.config` file (you don't need a `web.config` file in your actual project) with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <location>
    <system.webServer>

      <security xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
        <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
      </security>

    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

When you publish a release build this will get added. Very important to include the part `InsertIfMissing` or it will be ignored.

You DON'T need a third party package such as [this](https://github.com/nil4/dotnet-transform-xdt#-use-with-msbuildcsproj-tooling). 7

See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/transform-webconfig?view=aspnetcore-3.1