# allowdoubleescaping = "true" in IIS Express Config Not Working

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express, blazor

I get HTTP **Error 404.11 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that contains a double escape sequence.**
Error when I send a request to a .razor page in Blazor, The link is dynamically built and sent to users email:

```
string confirmationLink = $"{HttpContext.Request.Scheme}://{Request.Host}/account/confirmemail/{System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(user.Id)}/{System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(confirmationToken)}";
```

I modified the IIS Express config files in five places:

- web.config in "C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv"
- applicationhost.config in
  "C:\Program Files\IIS Express\AppServer"
- applicationhost.config in "C:\Program Files\IIS Express\config\templates\PersonalWebServer"
- applicationhost.config in "C:\Program Files (x86)\IISExpress\AppServer"
- applicationhost.config in "C:\Program Files(x86)\IIS Express\config\templates\PersonalWebServer"

In all cases I modified the

```
<requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true">
```

tag in "web.server" "security" section. But I still get the error. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Visual Studio does not use any of them, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/getting-started/features.html#add-iis-express-from-visual-studio-2015-2017-solution-file

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me...

1. To find the `applicationhost.config` file for IISExpress I looked for the `IIS Express` icon in the system tray (lower right corner of Windows 10).
2. I right-clicked on the IIS Express icon and clicked `"Show All Applications"`.
3. From the list of `Running Applications` I clicked on the `Site Name` whose config file I wanted to modify.
4. Once the site name was clicked the word `Config:` appeared below.
5. I clicked on the path to the right of `Config:` This opened the `applicationhost.config` file in Visual Studio.
6. There I clicked `Ctrl-F` and searched for `<requestFiltering>` which I changed to `<requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true">`