# Passing Plus Sign and Spaces in parameters of Web API in ASP .NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am trying to pass Mobile Number in Asp.NET MVC Core Web API's. For example 
https://api.test.com/GetMobileNumberAvailability/+971 99 999 9999/

My Controller file part looks like this:

```
[HttpGet("GetMobileNumberAvailability/{mobile}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Client>> GetMobileNumberAvailability(string mobile)
{
    var client = await _context.Clients.Where(client => client.Mobile == mobile).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    if (client == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return client;
}
```

Can anyone help how to deal with this?

Comment: You need to `UrlEncode` it from the caller side and decode it in your `GetMobileNumberAvailability` action.

Comment: Can you please help me with some example ?  I would be really obliged.

Comment: I would need to know the way you are calling that function from the frontend. Could you please update your Question, and include the front-end bits?

Comment: `trying to pass Mobile Number in Asp.NET MVC Core Web API` You can check this SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49679099/6751634

Answer (score 0):

Encode the mobile number before hitting the endpoint.
It looks like https://api.test.com/GetMobileNumberAvailability/%2B971%2099%20999%209999/

and decode the mobile

```
[HttpGet("GetMobileNumberAvailability/{mobile}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Client>> GetMobileNumberAvailability(string mobile)
        {
            mobile = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode(mobile).Trim();
            var client = await _context.Clients.Where(client => client.Mobile == mobile).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            if (client == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return client;
        }
```