# How do I allow restricted characters in the URL of a .net core application?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, web-config, special-characters

Previously, to allow for encoded special characters to be passed as part of a URL in a .net framework service, I've added this to the web.config file within the `system.web` node:

`<httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />`

What is the equivalent for a .net core application?

An example of the test data I need to allow would be 'searchterm%26' which is the encoded output of 'searchterm&'

Comment: Does this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42819825/allow-colon-in-url-for-asp-net-core-in-iis-azure answers your question?

Comment: I did see this but I don't think so? "system.web section of your current web.config isn't relevant to ASP.NET Core"